# HTML elements added via Javascript not visible on an iPhone (7)

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, iphone

[www.mpee.fi](https://www.mpee.fi)

I made myself a website to study things and to put my content in. I ran in to an issue where several friends report that on an iPhone (7) the **Photography section** doesn't work. It just shows blank section. It is impossible for me to pin down exactly where the issue lies since I don't have any Apple devices at hand. Firefox emulator claims everything works fine, but in practice on iPhone 7 the Photography section fails to display.

I don't know if it is a Javascript problem, which would be odd since I use exact same method to display other sections (basic Ajax+PHP+JSON setup)

Or maybe it's a CSS problem where I am missing some CSS setting for Apple products?

I am so sorry for so vague question, but the problem is specific to iPhone (tested on 7). So while the question is board, the problem is specific.

Comment: I have an iPhone 7 and it showed fine

Comment: @Dani Ok this is just weird then...you have probably updated your phone yes? and you are using default browser? (Safari is it?)

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: @Mikko-PenttiEinariEronen I have the latest ios and I am using safari

Comment: @Dani Thank you for your information. Then the mystery gets...more mysterious. They both sent me screenshots and for them the Photography section just shows an empty section. I guess I will have to keep shooting in the dark and try to figure out what could be the cause.